# Hairline borders between my tables in Gmail Android App

Tags: android, html, email, gmail, css-tables

I have been trying to find the issue for this for awhile now and I can't figure out why these thin hairline borders are appearing in Gmail Only. I have tried to set bgcolors on all the TD elements, even all my tables are border:collapse (see code below). Any help would be much appreciated. You can see these on the edges. It looks like a thin border slicing through the email horizontally.

The image is here as I can't post images just yet.

[http://imgur.com/Q7IfLnt](https://imgur.com/Q7IfLnt)

```
    table {
       border-collapse:collapse !important;
       border-spacing: 0 !important;
       Margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: The image is not available, making the question unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you inlined the css just to be sure
also put the border collapse on TDs too

Comment: The service I am using inlines it automatically (HubSpot) I have also tried using it with `table,td {...}` and it still doesn't work.